# Ionic using PounchDB fail

Tags: sqlite, cordova, ionic-framework

I`m testing PounchDB for my new app and, i receive this error when try execute this code:

```
PouchDB.plugin(require('pouchdb-adapter-cordova'));
_db = new PouchDB('mydb.db', {adapter: 'cordova-sqlite'});
```

Erro received:

> ReferenceError: Can't find variable: require

I follow instructions from: https://github.com/nolanlawson/pouchdb-adapter-cordova-sqlite

Using ionic 1.

Answer (score 0):

You're using `require` without an associated package manager or module bundler. `require` is not native to JavaScript -- you have to include a library or package your app in order for this to work.

I suggest JSPM (http://jspm.io), since it works with SystemJS and supports the newest ES2015 module syntax. However, it also understands `require`.

Alternatively, you can use `Browserify`(http://browserify.org) to bundle your code (essentially Browserify packs everything into one file, which is great for production!). Webpack(https://webpack.github.io) is also a great option. Both of these will add a build step to your development workflow, so be aware of that (but you should have one anyway).

Comment: Kerri, i solve this problem using 'cordova.require("pouchdb-adapter-cordova")' in my code! Thx!!!